# Symfony 4 Form Collection with prototypes

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, symfony4

I'm new to Symfony 4 and I'm trying to render a form with a ChoiceType Field with numeric choices in order to generate the exact Number of tags Chosen by the user.

This is my controller:

```
class ContactController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/matrix", name="matrix")
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $contact = new Contact();
// i've already added some tags
        $tag3 = new Tag();
        $tag3->setName('tag3');
        $contact->getTags()->add($tag3);

        $tag4=new Tag();
        $tag4->setName('ciao');
        $contact->getTags()->add($tag4);

        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $contactFormData = $form->getData();
            dump($contactFormData);
        }

        return $this->render('contact/index.html.twig', array(
            //'our_form' => $form,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

At this Point of my code, the form seems to be filled, I've checked with some dumps.

This is my twig

```
{% block body %}
    <div>
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
            {% for tag in form.tags %}
                <li> {{ form_row(tag.name) }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-success" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

It seems there's no visibility between this two Files, in fact, he is not able to enter into the for a loop. I've dumped some stuff and I've seen that tags have no children at this Point but it should.

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('motto')
            ->add('expectations', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'  => array(
                    '1' => '1',
                    '2' => '2',
                    '3' => '3',
                    '4' => '4',
                    '5' => '5',


                ),
            ));

$builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => TagType::class,
    'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
    'mapped' => false,

));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Configure your form options here
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ehy, why don' t 'u come in our chat (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165794/php-mysql-html-css-js-jq-wordpress)

Comment: Can you show us `ContactType::class` code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm perplex about this code => `$contact->getTags()->add($tag3);`. It seems `Tags` to be an entity and `Contact` another one so your `Contact` entity should have `adders`/`removers` and/or `setters`/`removers` (event if cumulate both is not necessary).

So your entity should like:

```php
class Contact
{
    // ...

    /** @var Collection */
    protected $tag;

    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...

    public function addTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        $this->tags->add($tag);
    }

    public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

A good example to implement your case: [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#form-collections-new-prototype)

Then i don't know what's your TagType form looks like but even if it's well develop your twig is not ok.

First `form_widget(form)` render the entire form

From Symfony Doc

> Renders the HTML widget of a given field. If you apply this to an entire form or collection of fields, each underlying form row will be rendered.

So re-render the collection will have no effect. And even if your twig code is not te good one to render a collection.